# Android: How can i change the formatting of decimal to scientific after specific number of digits have reached?

Tags: android, formatting

Im formatting my output string like this:

```
private DecimalFormat df4 = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
updateFinalResult(df4.format(currentInput));
```

I'd like to make it so that when the double `currentInput` have number of digits more than 14, then its starts showing in scientific notation. How may i achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Post some example, what type of result you want ?

Comment: eg updateFinalResult(String) is showing a double value currentInput. if the value of currentInput is say 7482975728.5724 (a 14 digit number), it is bieng shown in normal formating with upto 4 decimals (#.####). but once the number get even bigger like 582668582617595.5837 (more-than-14 digit number), i would like it to be shown as a scientific notation (5.8248337627E16) and back in normal notation once number gets smaller again

Answer (score 0):

If you want your double output "#.##"
 please try

```html
String.format("%.2f", d)
```

Comment: im already formating the double value upto 4 decimal places. what id like to do is to automatically start formatting into scientific notation once the value become more than a 14 digit number. and back into #.#### when the value is not 14 digit nuber anymore

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are asking for

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();

    double number = 1234567.4569847648;
    System.out.println(number);    

    formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.######E0"); // you can change this format to what ever you like
    System.out.println(formatter.format(number)); //output = 1.234567E6
```

Comment: the output is always in scientific notation with this format

Comment: thats just a demo, you need to implement your `conditions` before this